# HTML: redirect, but not refresh

Tags: javascript, html

How is this, conceptually, achieved?

e.g. access https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna (a google chrome extension download) and instead of installing it, close with the dialog X button.

I noticed that url changed, but content was not changed (well: the dialog was closed, but the rest of the page was not changed).

**Question**: How is that done? AFAIK when the url is changed, the page changes.

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an HTML5 feature. It support your javascript messing with your navigation history

An article I was reading yesterday:

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html